# Get substring after last occurrence of a space in a string

Tags: php, string, substring, text-extraction

```
echo $cookie[4];
```

Result:

```
#HttpOnly_bacohuracm FALSE / TRUE 0 PHPSESSID 3A8DB8BE067954EE327A56F7F8D8B19C
```

I want to delete this part:

```
#HttpOnly_bacohuracm FALSE / TRUE 0 PHPSESSID
```

and get only this part:

```
3A8DB8BE067954EE327A56F7F8D8B19C
```

I tried `preg_match()`, it has given a `null` result. I tried some other ways, and got the same `null` result and still couldn't figure out how I can do this job with PHP.

Comment: Show us what you tried. `preg_match()` **never** returns null.

Comment: can you filter that part with preg_match? can you show me an example, so it solves my problem

Comment: How about you show us what you tried first, so we can help you?

Comment: preg_match("/TRUE 0 PHPSESSID (.*?)/", $cookie[4], $newone);

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($cookie as $value)
    echo substr($value, strpos($value, 'PHPSESSID')+10);
```

Would work

Answer (score 0):

To return only what you're looking for:

```
$source = "#HttpOnly_bacohuracm FALSE / TRUE 0 PHPSESSID 3A8DB8BE067954EE327A56F7F8D8B19C";
preg_match("/PHPSESSID (\w+)$/", $source, $matches);
print $matches[1];
```

If this still returns null, is error text being suppressed? Is there anything related in the logs?